# storing dom element in variables for jquery doesn't work inside meteor

Tags: jquery, dom, meteor

Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

http://jsfiddle.net/zsVpt/

```
var loadingDOM = $('.loading');

//when i want to use the stored DOM, it simply doesn't work and don't give any errors at all !!!
Template.search.events({
    'keyup .searchField' : function(event, template){
        loadingDOM.css('display','inline');
        //etc.
     }
});


//this one works
Template.search.events({
    'keyup .searchField' : function(event, template){
        $('.loading').css('display','inline');
        //etc.
     }
});
```

It simple tho, get the dom and store it in a variable ( performance ) and then use it in the meteor events scope.

When i use use the stored DOM it simply doesn't work without giving any errors ! while getting the DOM directly with JQuery does work.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JP9zwE02tk4

Comment: A video? Well that's a new one.

Comment: @user1394965 hmm whats the point ?

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea to post a video. try to share something on jsfiddle

Comment: @mohamedmellouki The point is you should post your code here instead, more people will answer :)

Comment: @user1394965 question updated

Comment: laodingDom != LoadingDom (first l in uppercase)

Comment: @chumkiu just a typo in jsfidle still doesn't work, but thanks :)

Comment: the jsfiddle is totally wrong (missing jquery, missing image and missing Template)... try in local. If the second block really works, the only difference is there :-)

Comment: @chumkiu yep done ;) i used jsfiddle only for code display instead of here. still doesn't work !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try caching `loadingDOM` in a rendered callback, like this:

```
Template.search.rendered = function() {
    this.loading = this.find('.loading'); 
}

Template.search.events({
  'keyup input' : function(e, t){
     $(t.loading).css('display', 'inline'); 
   }
});
```

My guess is that you're trying to cache the loading dom element before the template has rendered. By caching it into the template object after the template has rendered, you'll have access to it as long as you're working within that same template.